# Why is my ID based TCP/IP server not working?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, server

I'm building a tcp/ip server in python that works with clients.
Each client gets its own thread and its socket is added to a list called client_list.
there also is a variable "clients_connected" which stores the amount of connected clients.
for some reason it just works with one client at the moment.
Also when a client disconnects, it should be removed from client_list but I'm not sure how to do that.
Could you take a look at the code please? thanks a lot!

this thread is looking for incoming connections:

```
    def addclientsthread(sock):
        global client_list
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        client_list += [conn]
        print_line('Client connected on ' + addr[0] + "\n")
        start_new_thread(clientthread, (conn,))
```

So when a client connects it gets its own "clientthread"

```
    def clientthread(conn):
        # handling connections.
        global clients_connected
        while True:
            # Receiving from client
            in_data = conn.recv(1024)
            data = decrypt(in_data)
            if data.lower().find("id=-1") != -1:
                clients_connected += 1
                print_line("new client ID set to " + str(clients_connected) + "\n")
                crypted_msg = encrypt("SID=" + str(clients_connected))
                conn.sendall(crypted_msg)
                pass
            elif data.lower().find("uin") == 0:
                uin_id = int(data[4:])
                clients_connected -= 1
                break
            else:
                print_line(data)
            if not data:
                break

        # If client disconnects
        conn.close()
```

Oh and please don't hate, I just started coding :)

EDIT: This is the main code (not in a thread)

```
    HOST = ''
    PORT = 8820
    clients_connected = 0
    client_list = []
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print('Socket created')

    # Bind socket to host and port
    try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error, msg:
        print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit()

    print 'Socket successfully binded'

    # Start listening on socket
    s.listen(100000)
    print 'Socket is listening'

    start_new_thread(addclientsthread, (s,))
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. The problem is probably in the `start_new_thread` function, or maybe `addclientsthread` is only called once.

Comment: As for removing a disconnected client: `client_list.remove(conn)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! the addclientsthread is indeed called just once in the main program. What is the best way to make it listen the entire time? I'm thinking about a `while True` loop in the thread, but im not sure if that would work.

Comment: Oh and the `client_list.remove(conn)` indeed works great!

Comment: `addclientsthread` is called after a `listen` call, right? Instead of calling it once, put it in a loop to keep calling it. `accept` blocks until the next client connect request comes in.

Comment: I added more code, this is just like the main code being executed, its not in a thread. Could you explain what I need to loop?

Comment: Just change `start_new_thread(addclientsthread, (s,))` to `while True: addclientsthread(s)`.

Comment: you guys are amazing! thanks a lot :)